# c# winform textbox databind to property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, textbox, bind

I have a form with some textboxes, below is my code :

```
public partial class Test : Form
{
    private readonly ICustomerBl _customerBl;
    private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource1;

    public Test(ICustomerBl customerBl)
    {
        _bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

        _customerBl = customerBl;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    private void Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Method 1
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Customer, "Name"));

        // Method 2
        textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bindingSource1, "Email", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_customerBl.Get(textBox1.Text) != null)
        {
            Customer = _customerBl.Get(textBox1.Text).First();
            _bindingSource1.Add(Customer);
        }
    }
```

**Customer.cs**

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string JoinDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public virtual string TaxId { get; set; }
    public virtual double CreditLimit { get; set; }
    protected internal virtual IList<RentalAgreement> RentalAgreements { get; protected set; }
    protected internal virtual IList<RentalWithdrawal> RentalWithdrawals { get; protected set; }

    public virtual RentalAgreement GetActiveRental()
    {
        return RentalAgreements.FirstOrDefault(rental => rental.Status == "ACTIVE");
    }

    public virtual bool HasRentalAgreement()
    {
        return RentalAgreements.Count > 0;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
```

I tried to use 2 methods as above shows, but none works.

Needing some input here.

Thanks !

Update :

Sorry for not being clear, my question is how to correctly achieve databinding between a textbox and a property, in this case the property has a type of Customer. And I expect the databinding to update the textbox2 with Customer.Name when I updated the form's Customer property.

Thanks !

Comment: `And your actually questions is what..????`

Comment: Um, sorry if I'm not being clear. My question is, how to achieve databinding between a textbox and a property of object. :)

Comment: Why not use a `BindingList` and create 2 separate ones. you are probably getting the same data in both text boxes, if so that's the reason why..look into using `BindingList`

Comment: You should show the code of your `Customer` class. That class should implement `IBindableComponent` so that you can use it in a Data binding relation.

Comment: @KingKing I added customer class

Comment: @SamuelAdam what is `Entity` does it implement `IBindableComponent`?

Comment: @KingKing Nope, it's only an abstract class where all my entity derived from.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Customer` class should implement `IBindableComponent` like this:

```
public class Customer : Entity, IBindableComponent {
     //Your code
     //Members of IBindableComponent
     ISite iSite;
     ControlBindingsCollection dataBindings;
     BindingContext bindingContext = new BindingContext();
     public Customer(){
         dataBindings = new ControlBindingsCollection(this);
     }
     public event EventHandler Disposed;
     public void Dispose(){
         //your code for disposing
     }
     public BindingContext BindingContext {
        get { return bindingContext;}
        set {bindingContext = value;}
     }
     public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings {
        get { return dataBindings;}
     }
     public ISite Site {
        get { return iSite;}
        set {iSite = value;}
     }
}
```

All the members of `IBindableComponent` should be added to your `Customer` class, you may want to search more on how to implement `IBindableComponent` interface.

Comment: I actually figured out why my code is not working, it's because when I bind Customer.Name to textbox3, Customer is still null which strangely throw a silent exception which requires a try catch block to show.
Now I need to find out how to bind even though the object is null at the beginning.

Comment: I think if your `Customer` is null, there should be an exception thrown, I don't think the exception could be silent. `DataBindings` requires the data source and of course the control itself are not null. You can't bind data that way. If your `Customer` becomes null and loaded with new data then, you have to add data binding again, ... You should load some data into it, that's the only way. Even you load data into your `Customer`, my code above is still needed to bind it's Properties with some other controls'.